# Нужно запарсить массив JSON-объектов

Tags: java, android

Есть массив JSON-объектов, которые я не могу запарсить, объектов 20 штук, у всех 3 одинаковых поля. Банально не могу найти методы парсинга массива json-объектов, кусок массива прилагается

Answer (score 4):

Если у вас JSON хранится как строка то вот один из вариантов:

```
import org.json.JSONArray;

       try {
          JSONArray array = new JSONArray("[{a:1},{a:2}]");
            for(int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                int a = array.getJSONObject(i).getInt("a");
                System.out.println(a);
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Если JSON хранится в папке ресурсов, например RAW или Assets, то я обычно делаю так.

1 Вам нужно сгенерить POJO для вашего массива.
2 Я себе сделал такой класс JsonReader

```
MyJSONReader {

public String readJsonDataFromFile(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {

    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    try {
        String jsonDataString = null;

        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader
                (new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"));

        while ((jsonDataString = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            builder.append(jsonDataString);
        }
    } finally {
        if (inputStream != null) {
            inputStream.close();
        }
    }
    return new String(builder);
}
```

}

в него я закидываю массив где нужно и раскидываю его в адаптер `RecyclerView`/
Выглядит это так:

```
private void createlListFromJson(){
    try {

        MyJSONReader myJsonReader = new MyJSONReader();
        InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.myJsonFile);
        String jsonString = myJsonReader.readJsonDataFromFile(inputStream);
        JSONArray JsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonString);

        for (int i = 0; i < JsonArray.length(); ++i) {

            JSONObject ItemObject = JsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

            String title = ItemObject.getString("title");
            String author = ItemObject.getString("author ");

             ItemList itemList= new ItemList (title, author);
            List.add(itemList);
        }


    } catch (IOException | JSONException exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Во фрагмента:

```
  @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    createlListFromJson();
}


public View onCreateView.....

recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    Adapter mAdapter = new Adapter(List);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```